# How can I find match string in array javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I find a match in an array of strings using Javascript? For example:

```
var str = "https://exmaple.com/u/xxxx?xx=x";
var filter = ["/u","/p"];
if (!str.includes(filter)){
  return 1;
}
```

In the above code I want to search for var `str` if match this two values of array `filter`

Comment: Your goal isn't clear. Do you mean that you want to return the *index* of the matching element in the array?

Comment: In the above code I want to search for var str if match this two index of array filter

Comment: That doesn't really clear it up. It's your misuse of the word 'index' that's confusing matters. What should the response be from the lookup?

Comment: i mean values instead of 'index'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```js
var str = "https://exmaple.com/u/xxxx?xx=x";
var filters = ["/u","/p"];

for (const filter of filters) {
  if (str.includes(filter)) {
    console.log('matching filter:', filter);
    break; // return 1; if needed
  }
}
```

Comment: i have edited the question.

Comment: updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your array you need to find the element which `includes` `"/u"`. filter will return an array and will contain only those element which includes `u`

```js
var x = ["https://exmaple.com/u/xxxx?xx=x", "https://exmaple.com/p/xxxx?xx=x"];
let matched = x.filter(item => item.includes("/u"));

console.log(matched)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var x = ["https://exmaple.com/u/xxxx?xx=x","https://exmaple.com/p/xxxx?xx=x"], i;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if(x[i].includes('/u')) {
    document.write(x[i]);
  }
}
```

This loops through all the URLs and picks the one that has `/u` in it. Then it just prints that out.